# What happens if cursor.executemany fails in Python

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `cursor.executemany` to insert thousands of rows into snowflake database from some other source. So if in case the insert fails due to some reason, does it rollback all the inserts?

Is there some way to insert only if the same row does not exist yet? There is no primary key nor unique key in the table

Comment: yes, you can run a merge statement and do nothing if it there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

> So if in case the insert fails due to some reason, does it rollback all the inserts?

The `cursor.executemany(…)` implementation in Snowflake's Python Connector [fills a multi-row INSERT INTO command](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/6d0ea3f/cursor.py#L755-L818), whose values are pre-evaluated by the query compiler before the inserts run, so they all run together or fail early if a value is unacceptable to its defined column type.

> Is there some way to insert only if the same row does not exist yet? There is no primary key nor unique key in the table

If there are no ID-like columns, you'll need to define a condition that qualifies two rows to be the same (such as a multi-column match).

Assuming your new batch of inserts are in a temporary table `TEMP`, the following SQL can insert into the `DESTINATION` table by performing a check of all rows against a set from the `DESTINATION` table.

Using [`HASH(…)`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html) as a basis for comparison, comparing all columns in each row together (in order):

```sql
INSERT INTO DESTINATION
  SELECT *
  FROM TEMP
  WHERE
    HASH(*) IS NOT IN ( SELECT HASH(*) FROM DESTINATION )
```

As suggested by [Christian in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113970/what-happens-if-cursor-executemany-fails-in-python#comment109856853_62113970), the [`MERGE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#merge) SQL command can also be used, once you have an identifier strategy (join keys). This too requires the new rows to be placed in a temporary table first, and offers an ability to perform an `UPDATE` if a row is already found.

**Note**: `HASH(…)` may have collisions and isn't the best fit. Better is to form an identifier using one or more of your table's columns, and compare them together. Your question lacks information about table and data characteristics, so I've picked a very simple approach involving `HASH(…)` here.